# Merging ADO.NET DataSets to import data does INSERT but does not UPDATE

Tags: sql-server-2008, import, datatable, merge, dataset

I have two identical SQL-Server databases on two different servers, and I am using the following code to import data from one table in the remote database into the same table in the local database. New rows are being inserted properly. However, modified rows are not getting updated. Any clue about what I am doing wrong?

```
SqlConnection connectionA = new SqlConnection(connectionStringToDatabaseA);
connectionA.Open();

SqlDataAdapter adapterA = new SqlDataAdapter(
    string.Format("select * from MyTable where MyDate='{0}'", today.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")),
    connectionA);
SqlCommandBuilder commandA = new SqlCommandBuilder(adapterA);
adapterA.MissingSchemaAction = MissingSchemaAction.AddWithKey;
DataSet dataSetA = new DataSet("MyTable");
adapterA.Fill(dataSetA);

DataColumn[] myKey = new DataColumn[2];
myKey[0] = dataSetA.Tables[0].Columns["MyDate"];
myKey[1] = dataSetA.Tables[0].Columns["SequenceNumber"];
dataSetA.Tables[0].Constraints.Clear();
dataSetA.Tables[0].Constraints.Add("myKey", myKey, true);

SqlConnection connectionB = new SqlConnection(connectionStringToDatabaseB);
connectionB.Open();
SqlDataAdapter adapterB = new SqlDataAdapter(
    string.Format("select * from MyTable where DateAbat='{0}'", today.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")),
    connectionB);
SqlCommandBuilder commandB = new SqlCommandBuilder(adapterB);

adapterB.MissingSchemaAction = MissingSchemaAction.AddWithKey;
DataSet dataSetB = new DataSet("MyTable");
adapterB.Fill(dataSetB);

myKey[0] = dataSetB.Tables[0].Columns["MyDate"];
myKey[1] = dataSetB.Tables[0].Columns["SequenceNumber"];
dataSetB.Tables[0].Constraints.Clear();
dataSetB.Tables[0].Constraints.Add("myKey", myKey, true);

foreach (DataRow dr in dataSetA.Tables[0].Rows)
{
    string sequenceNumber = dr["SequenceNumber"].ToString();
    DataView dv = new DataView(dataSetB.Tables[0], "SequenceNumber=" + sequenceNumber, string.Empty, DataViewRowState.CurrentRows);
    if (dv.Count == 0)
        dr.SetAdded();
    else
        dr.SetModified();
}

dataSetB.Tables[0].Merge(dataSetA.Tables[0], false, MissingSchemaAction.AddWithKey);
adapterB.Update(dataSetB);
```